# Client send RST after 3way handshake when server listen on 80, change a port it is ok

Tags: tcp, socketasynceventargs

I write a customized HTTP server based on SocketAsyncEventArgs (C#) instead of commercial software. When the server is listening on Port 8080/12345... it is ok. But only on Port 80 it appears like this when the browser launching a connection with HTTP request:

- 2785: [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
- 2786: [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
- 2787: [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65700 Len=0
- 2788: [RST] Seq=1 Win=65536 Len=0
- 3538: HTTP   767 GET /push_push.do?imei=356708041124742&simno=4600230... blah blah

Notice that, when client is sending HTTP request like "socket.Send(http_bytes);", TCP messages No. 2788 [RST] and No. 3538 [Normal HTTP request] are send consecutively.

========================

Please give me an advice about:

- How does the [RST] come from and how to avoid it ?
- Why the listening port affect ?

Comment: I cannot imagine that your [RST] has something to do with 'restructuredtext', so I removed this tag.

Comment: I'm sorry when I tagged 'RST' it was implicitly the abbreviation of ReStrcuredText...